# How to specify type for object in php using interface?

Tags: php

Is it possible to create object with custom type using interface like:

```
IHouse {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

$house<IHouse> = object();
$house.id = 1;
$house.name = "Bobs";
```

It works in TypeSript, and any IDE knows how to fill object when I type `$house.`

Comment: I know it may shock you but PHP and TypeScript are not even remotely compatible.

Comment: Not supported in PHP